# How do I determine whether a cell in the first record of a customers history contains a value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I have a Tickets table that holds several years with of customer data. I am trying to determine whether a customer who has visited x number of time used a coupon on their first visit. I have this (SQL below) which I am using so that I can break out the group I am looking for. What I really want to know about this group is how many of them used a coupon on their first visit (earliest SaleDate).

```
;WITH T AS
(
SELECT CustomerId, SaleDate, TotalCoupons,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID) as Cnt
FROM    Store.dbo.Tickets
Where   (CreationDate between '2014-1-1' and '2014-11-12')
        and (IsDeleted = 0)
        And (TicketStatus = 'Complete')
)
SELECT CustomerID, SaleDate, TotalCoupons, Cnt                   
FROM T
WHERE Cnt = 10
order by CustomerId, SaleDate
```

As an end result I just need a count and don't need to see the CustomerID, SaleDate etc, I just need a (pseudo) Select Count(CustomerID) where TotalCoupons cell has a value on it and it is the earliest record for that CustomerID.

I think I have to add a RowID and use a Where RowID = 1 but I am not sure how to work it into what I have done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to determine the first visit and then use conditional aggregation.  The following gets the customers in the group with the flag:

```
WITH T AS (
      SELECT CustomerId, SaleDate, TotalCoupons,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID) as Cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY SaleDate) as seqnum
      FROM Store.dbo.Tickets
      Where (CreationDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-11-12') and
            (IsDeleted = 0) and
            (TicketStatus = 'Complete')
     )
SELECT CustomerID, SaleDate, TotalCoupons, Cnt,
       MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 and TotalCoupons IS NOT NULL) as HasCouponFirstVisit              
FROM T
WHERE Cnt = 10;
```

You can get a count of them by doing:

```
WITH T AS (
      SELECT CustomerId, SaleDate, TotalCoupons,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID) as Cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY SaleDate) as seqnum
      FROM Store.dbo.Tickets
      Where (CreationDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-11-12') and
            (IsDeleted = 0) and
            (TicketStatus = 'Complete')
     )
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID)
FROM T
WHERE Cnt = 10 AND seqnum = 1 AND TotalCoupons IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm not sure if the `TotalCoupons IS NOT NULL` is exactly what you are looking for, but it should be close enough.